# GitHub codespace not detecting Flutter SDK (Chrome)

Tags: android, flutter, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, sdk

Could not find a Flutter SDK. Please ensure flutter is installed and in your PATH (you may need to restart).

[image]

How can I solve this?